# How do I remove Windows Mobile Device Center from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-mobile

How do I remove Windows Mobile Device Center from Windows 7?

When I connect any mobile device, I don't want Windows Mobile Device Center to pop up, like ActiveSync 4.5 did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User [flapjack](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=574279)'s solution on [xda-developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=394984):

> I was able to fix this. First, I
>   stopped and disabled both WMDC
>   services under Computer Management >
>   Services. Then, I found mobsync.exe in
>   the Windows/System32 folder, went into
>   "Permissions" for it, took ownership,
>   then removed all the accounts except
>   the "Everyone" permissions. For
>   Everyone, I set it to "Deny All".
>
> I now have no WMDC or sync stuff
>   popping up. It's great. I can still
>   browse the phone from My Computer >
>   TYTN II. I can also still use
>   MyMobiler to control the phone from
>   Windows, so this doesn't kill the USB
>   connection at all.
>
> Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Another user from the xda.developers forums has created a program that achieves just what you're looking for: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=1843786&postcount=2.